# weird index 2 beyond bounds for empty array error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I can't seem to find what's wrong. here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *sortedActivities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.trainingSession.activities.count];
for (ManagedActivity *activity in self.trainingSession.activities)
    [sortedActivities insertObject:activity atIndex:[activity.activityIndex unsignedIntegerValue]];
```

as you can see i want to sort the set of activities (which is a relation in trainingSession) by the a property named activityIndex inside the activity. the indexes of the activities are always from 0 on, that means that none of the indexes exceeds trainSession.activities.count-1.

i do the sorting by allocating a NSMutableArray with the appropriate capacity, and then iterate over the activities (once) and insert them to the right index. for some reason that i don't know i get this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'

i tried retaining the array, it didn't matter (and shouldn't matter).

the indexes are correct, the count is correct, what is wrong??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capacity in `arrayWithCapacity:` is just a hint for optimization. The array still has a count of 0.

Comment: so i can't insert straight to let's say index 3? should i fill it up first with NSNulls and then do the sorting? or just sort using blocks and comparators?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Both strategies will work; The block-based one would probably be a tiny bit faster, but I don't think the performance will be noticeable. It will probably be barely measurable for a relatively small array with just a few hundred entries.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your array count its not getting item at position 2